# Query running continuously in a PostgreSQL instance on AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm using the RDS Performance Insights view in AWS as a work list for PostgreSQL queries to optimize. There is one query that seems to be running continuously that I can't figure out what is. The query is:

```
FETCH FORWARD 10000 FROM "report"
```

[image: The fetch forward query]

As far as I can tell there is no table or view in the database named `report`. The query is running 1.3 times per second with an average latency of 600ms, so pretty much continuously.

Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something created a cursor and is now fetching data from that cursor. If needed, kill the database connection and block the database role from connecting again.

Comment: The traffic appears be coming from the jumpbox used by developers to access the servers, so I can't really block the role. It's been going on for weeks it seems.

Comment: Rebooting the jump server killed the process though. Thanks.